# Result set for string concatenated stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Am building a string concatenated stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server in which am facing a problem that result set was set not inherited in Entity Framework.

```
Create Procedure SPName
AS
Begin
Declare @sql varchar(max)
Declare @TotalCount varchar(max)
Select @sql = 'Select param1,param2 from Table1'
Select @TotalCount  = 'Select count(*) from Table1'
Execute sp_executesql @sql 
Execute sp_executesql @TotalCount  
End
```

Let me know if am making any mistake here

Comment: Did you tried varchar as nvarchar and checked !!!

Comment: Show your EF code. You return multiple resultsets which make things more complicated. One of the results is actually a scalar and won't have a column name so it is not mappable/translatable to an instance in C#. Finally, it does not look like you need a stored procedure at all.

Comment: @Malcolm I have checked with that too but still not works

Comment: @Pawel Even I have tried with single execute statement bit it not works.